# How do you disable rearrange/edit when you have more than 5 items?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My tab bar currently has more than 5 items, so it is showing up as "More ***", which is fine. However, when the user is in more, they have the ability to click edit, and rearrange what's in the tab bar. How do I disable this for the user?

I finally figured it out, but since i am a new user they won't let me answer my own question lol, so here is the answer.

I figured it out, so I created my own UITabBarController files and in the .m file I added:

```
self.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

into the viewDidLoad method, like so:

```
#import "MyTabBarController.h"

@interface MyTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation MyTabBarController



- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   self.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to view did load.

```
self.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
        willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
        animated:(BOOL)animated {

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *item = bar.topItem;

    item.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

Okay you can hide navigation bar like that

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

if you are not on iOS 4.0
Try

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    tabBarController.customizableViewControllers=nil;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to xCode development. Where do I include this code? I'm not using a navigationController, but a Tab Bar Controller.